# Will sdio_register_driver() creatre a device name?

Tags: android, c, linux, kernel, linux-device-driver

I read code like below. Is a device name "my_sdio" created in /dev after sdio_register_driver() or after my_sdio_probe() is called? If neither of them, when is the device name created?

```
static struct sdio_driver my_sdio_driver = {
   .name    = "my_sdio",
   .id_table = my_sdio_ids,
   .probe   = my_sdio_probe,
   .remove  = my_sdio_remove,
};

sdio_register_driver(&my_sdio_driver);
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `sdio_register_driver()` nor `my_sdio_probe()` creates the device by name `my_sdio`.

The function `sdio_register_driver` will register your driver to the kernel.
The device will be created by registering the device to kernel. Usually in application code using `register_blkdev` or `register_chrdev`. Here you will give the name `my_sdio` for your device.

The `name` parameter in the structure below helps binding of your driver to the device (which is created in application code).

```
static struct sdio_driver my_sdio_driver = {
   .name    = "my_sdio",
   .id_table = my_sdio_ids,
   .probe   = my_sdio_probe,
   .remove  = my_sdio_remove,
};
```

The `my_sdio_probe()` function is called only after finding a match between device and driver.

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt

Driver binding is performed automatically by the driver core, invoking
driver probe() after finding a match between device and driver.  If the
probe() succeeds, the driver and device are bound as usual.  There are
three different ways to find such a match:

```
- Whenever a device is registered, the drivers for that bus are
  checked for matches.  Platform devices should be registered very
  early during system boot.

- When a driver is registered using platform_driver_register(), all
  unbound devices on that bus are checked for matches.  Drivers
  usually register later during booting, or by module loading.

- Registering a driver using platform_driver_probe() works just like
  using platform_driver_register(), except that the driver won't
  be probed later if another device registers.  (Which is OK, since
  this interface is only for use with non-hotpluggable devices.)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question is the my_sdio_probe() function is not called by Kernel, though the Micro-SD card has been inserted. I am thinking the

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Another question is the my_sdio_probe() function is not called by Kernel, though the Micro-SD card has been inserted. I think sdio_device_id is not set correctly. How can I know the vendor and device IDs, class ... of my Micro SD card? I tried SDIO_DEVICE_CLASS(SDIO_CLASS_UART). It does not work either.

Comment: Here is what I set for another trial. It can not get my_sdio_probe() called either.

static const struct sdio_device_id my_sdio_ids[] = {
    { .class=SDIO_ANY_ID, .vendor=SDIO_ANY_ID, .device=SDIO_ANY_ID},
    { /* Terminating entry */   },
};

Comment: @user1443721 I am now on same ship . Did you solve this issue ?